# application crashes when an activity starts

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2, android-permissions

Im creating an application in which I have to show map when the button is clicked. But when the map button is clicked instead of showing map the application crash and it said "Unfortunately, 'Application' has stopped" here is my code:

java file:

```
package com.example.jamaattiming;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.example.jamaat_times.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class TagYourself extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag_yourself);

        /* MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();

         GoogleMap maps;
         maps=(((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap());*/


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tag_yourself, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

here's the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#808080">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jamaat_times"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_jamaat"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.MainPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.CLEARSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.Qibla"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.COMPASS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.JamaatFinder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_jamaat_finder" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.QiblaFinder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_qibla_finder" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.TagYourself"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tag_yourself" >
         </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.NearbySearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nearby_search" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.ManualSearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manual_search" >
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is the log cat:

> 04-01 00:32:36.587: I/SurfaceTextureClient(18546): [STC::queueBuffer]
>   (this:0x518786b0) fps:0.88, dur:2279.85, max:1974.08, min:305.77 04-01
>   00:32:36.990: V/Provider/Settings(18546): invalidate [system]: current
>   214 != cached 0 04-01 00:32:37.020: D/ActivityThread(18546):
>   installProvider: 04-01 00:32:37.034: V/Provider/Settings(18546): from
>   db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0 04-01 00:32:37.223:
>   D/mylog(18546): Wifi State true 04-01 00:32:38.102:
>   D/ActivityThread(18546): getPackageInfo: securityViolation=true 04-01
>   00:32:38.102: W/asset(18546): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path
>   not exsit! 04-01 00:32:38.741: I/Google Maps Android API(18546):
>   Google Play services client version: 4242000 04-01 00:32:39.025:
>   I/Google Maps Android API(18546): Google Play services package
>   version: 4324034 04-01 00:32:39.538: D/AndroidRuntime(18546): Shutting
>   down VM 04-01 00:32:39.538: W/dalvikvm(18546): threadid=1: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419b19a8) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.jamaat_times/com.example.jamaattiming.TagYourself}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class fragment 04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   com.example.jamaattiming.TagYourself.onCreate(TagYourself.java:16)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  ... 11 more 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546): Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional
>   following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a
>   correct behavior: 04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):
>    04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at maps.e.ci.a(Unknown Source)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown
>   Source) 04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at maps.e.bh.a(Unknown Source)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown
>   Source) 04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   etu.onTransact(SourceFile:107) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown
>   Source) 04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source) 04-01 00:32:39.709:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4735) 04-01
>   00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
>   04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):  ... 21 more`enter code
>   here`

Comment: did you actually read the error before asking your question ?

Comment: I'm a beginner in android. I read it but couldn't understood anything that was why I posted it here. Now I'm learning to read the error here.

Comment: While reading those error stacktraces it is important to discover the root cause. Watch out for the `Caused by:` parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line of your logcat:

```
 Caused by:
java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior: 04-01 00:32:39.709: 
E/AndroidRuntime(18546): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 04-01 00:32:39.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18546):   at maps.e.ci.a(Unknown Source)
```

Looks like you forgot to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to your **AndroidManifest** xml file